# How can I create a redirect for Apache 2.2 webserver on Windows-7

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, webpage, redirection

I'd like to have a redirection web page from one page to another so that I can have two names for the same web page on my server.  I tried creating a windows shortcut, but that did not work.  Please suggest how to have one page be a pointer to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing in my virtual host section of the configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\myDocs"
ServerName www.domain.com
Redirect /index.html http://www.domain.com/anotherLocation
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: @WilliamKF - was the correct answer then from taspeotis or from you?  Appears as though you answered your own question correctly.  You should give yourself credit for that.

Answer (score 1):

This belongs on Server Fault. This is a server question, regarding Apache running on the Windows platform.

> two names for the same web page on my server

What are you trying to do? Are you trying to have Apache serve http://www.domain.com as well as http://domain.com?

If you are trying to have localhost/a.htm and localhost/b.htm point to c.htm you could try mod_alias or mod_rewrite.

Comment: I'm trying to have the following be the same:

    http://www.domain.com/directory/index.html
    http://www.domain.com/index.html

Without duplicating the page.

Comment: I couldn't get the 'Alias' command to work for me, but the 'Redirect' did work.  Think it had to do with permissions.